# How do I run heroku-toolbelt commands without the `--app` parameter

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I used to run `heroku create` and deploying with `git push heroku master` but I've since moved onto a Github based workflow where code is first pushed to my Github repo, and deployed via a web hook.

I now have to run `--app appname` or `-a appname` after every command, and it gets annoying.

e.g.

```
heroku run rails db:migrate -a appname # instead of
heroku run rails db:migrate

heroku run rails console -a appname # instead of
heroku run rails console

heroku run logs -t -a appname # instead of
heroku run logs -t
```

How do I force heroku-toolbelt to link this repo to the heroku app so that I can run `heroku` without the `--app` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a remote named `heroku` with the url `https://git.heroku.com/appname.git`

Run this:

```
$ git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
```

Comment: Worked for me, would be useful to know why, though...  ?

Comment: Can confirm even in case where git repo of name appname doesn't exist, (i.e. app is named differently to repo), this still works, so long as you use appname.git as the remote above. (for avoidance of doubt I am also deploying via github, not heroku git, as the question asks).